# Add ssh key in existing droplet

Tags: digital-ocean, ssh-keys

I am a new to use a digital ocean....
Unfortunately I am facing a problem when
I have a current (existing) droplet in which I need to add my ssh key? (DigitalOcean)
Can i update a droplet? | DigitalOcean

Comment: You can try this and generate a new key using console https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2
If that works with multiple keys it should would with your program too else program needs to checked.

Answer (score 1):

Edit and Add your new SSH key in authorized_keys file of .ssh directory, which is located in user directory.

then run following command

sudo service ssh restart

Then try to connect using ***ssh username@your_droplet_ipaddress***

I hope it works